# set the text direction in WebView to RTL

Tags: android, webview, text-align

how can I change text direction to the Right to Left in webview ?

This is my code

```
WebView web = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.web);
web.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
web.loadDataWithBaseURL("", myhtml, "text/html", "UTF-8", "");
```

Answer (score 21):

I think that you need to change the dir="RTL in your HTML code.
for example:

```
<body dir="rtl">
   <p>Some Text that will be RTL aligned</p>
</body>
```

WebView just allow you to view webpages but doesn't change the text direction. That only depends on the HTML markup in the web page.

If it still doesn't work, you might have issues in your HTML. You can share your code here and I can try to help you further.

Tom.

Answer (score 19):

it work for me:

```
desc.loadDataWithBaseURL("http://www.atfonline.ir/", "<html dir=\"rtl\" lang=\"\"><body>" + outhtml + "</body></html>", "text/html", "UTF-8", null);
```

Comment: what is desc? what is outhtml?

Comment: @PrajwalW `desc` is **Webview** object which is `web` in first question.